# ionic - tabs not fixed at bottom of the screen

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-tabs

I'm having an issue when trying to use ionic tabs.

I need them to be always visible at the bottom of the screen (something like `position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0;`).

They problem I've got is that in my current setup, is not behaving like supposed to.

Here's the template I'm using:

```
  <h2>This is subview</h2>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item " ng-repeat="el in elements">
      {{el.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="tabs tabs-icon-only tabs-dark">
        <a class="tab-item">test</a>
        <a class="tab-item">test 1</a>
        <a class="tab-item">test 2</a>
    </div>
```

but the tabs are linked to the bottom of the screen, and so, if i have to scroll the page, the are at the bottom instead of always visible with the content scrolling below on a different z-index.

I may have explained this badly, so here's an example that explains this better:
http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/NNZYwK?editors=1010

And to summarize: What I have to do to have the tabs always fixed to the bottom even if the page is longer?

PS: All of this refers to a sub view, if it is important somehow.

Thanks for any advice and help

Comment: Why are you not using the ion-tab directive? Using that, will automatically align itself to the ion-view. See [Ionic Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/)

Comment: tried the tabs directive, it does the same, it doesn't work. http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/NNZYwK?editors=1010

Comment: need to play with the style `ion-tabs { position: fixed; left: 0px, bottom: 0px }`. But having said that, the tabs are in a subview which is inside a view is bit messed.

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure that that is the reason why is not behaving like wanted. I basically have <ion-view><ion-content><tabs></ion-content></ion-view> currently. I also tried with the custom style, but it wasn't really fixed to the bottom of the screen but was moving on scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I solved this moving the tabs one level up so that they are not in the subview anymore, and copied some of the scope events into the main controller instead of the subview controller.

Here's the code that I changed: http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/NNZYwK?editors=1010

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
      <h1>Details for id</h1>      
      Below the line, subview content:
      <hr>
      <div ui-view="myDetailsSubview"></div>

    </ion-content>

    <ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top">      
      <ion-tab>test 1</ion-tab>
      <ion-tab>test 2</ion-tab>     
      <ion-tab>test 3</ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>

</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your whole app structure is a little messed up. You can see a working example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdLEye

You should probably consider using the `<ion-tabs>` directive with `<ion-tab>` to construct the tabs. Also your tabs need to be the next script after `<ion-nav-view>` and have your list inside `<ion-content>`.

**EDIT based on comment:**

You could make a directive for hiding the tabs like this:

```
.directive('hideTabs', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $el) {
      $rootScope.hideTabs = 'tabs-item-hide';
      $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $rootScope.hideTabs = '';
      });
    }
  };
})
```

And then use it in your templates like this:

```
<ion-view hide-tabs></ion-view>
```

And also include this in the tabs:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top {{$root.hideTabs}}">
```

The tabs will be then hidden in this particular view. You can also revert it to a `show-tabs` directive if you only a few pages where you want to show it and hide it elsewhere.

Comment: My problem is that I have a subview insie a view. My current template is <ion-view><ion-content><tabs></ion-content></ion-view> and that's the reason why i didn't add any other view or content. According to your suggestion, it should be <ion-view><ion-content><ion-view><ion-content><ion-content><tabs><ion-content><ion-view> and that doesn't work. the test is overlapping

Comment: To solve this, i need to move the tabs up (so they are not in the subview). If i do that, then it works fine. I was after a solution to put them inside a subview

Comment: I was just about to ask that you want the tabs only on the subview right? Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if i can have them in the subview

Comment: Thanks for the example, but i don't really want to hide them. I need to display them only in some specific subviews. I may end up writing a directive as an attribute and then fix the tabs at the bottom of the viewport if the attribute is present on subview container.

Comment: You can convert my answer as `ng-if="{{$root.hideTabs}}"` or something. But yeah good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `<ion-content>` `<ion-content scroll="false">` Im not quite sure, but you maybe have to add it outside the ion-content, but i wish you best fo luck!